# Reading multipile files independently

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have a rather large code for the data analysis software Root (CERN) and I have a run of data that I want to look through for bad runs. I have them all in one directory, but want to write a segment of code to take one file out of this folder at a time, run the code, output the resulting graphs, then take the next file.. etc. I am using a macro to run this code as it is now. I am hoping to just add something to that macro. I am somewhat novice to programming.

```
gSystem->Load("AlgoCompSelector_C.so");
// make the chains
std::string filekey;
TChain tree1 = new TChain("tree");
filekey = std::string("data/run715604.EEmcTree_Part1.root");
tree1->Add( filekey.data() );
```

Comment: Why don't you just change this to process only one file and exit, and launch one of those processes for each file on the directory?

Comment: When you use the word *macro* in a question tagged "C++," people are going to assume you mean you have a C++ macro, but I suspect that's not the case with you. What kind of macro do you have? How do you run it now?

Comment: @ Rob i have a file called AlgoCompSelector.C, which is then run by the program runAlgoCompSelector.C after I compile the first.

@m0skit0 I could do that, but i want to just write something that runs and exits all of them, with no manual selection of cases. there's a lot of data in the high energy physics world...

Comment: Do you want your solution in C++? I suspect that there are far better languages for your task (like using `bash` or `cmd` scripts) If you want C++, please post some existing code to make it clearer what you have and what you need.

Comment: my code has to be run in c++ for the data analysis software to read it: here is a bit of how my data gets read into my program: 

 gSystem->Load("AlgoCompSelector_C.so");

   // make the chains                                                                                                                      
   std::string filekey;

   TChain *tree1 = new TChain("tree");
   filekey = std::string("data/run715604*.EEmcTree_Part1.root");
   tree1->Add( filekey.data() );

Comment: like i said, this may be Root specific to some degree.

Comment: then this style of read-in gets repeated for each branch of the tree that I want to load for the file, and this pulls from a large data file (linked symbolically to my directory) which contains hundreds of thousands of events...

Comment: I think you won't notice a big difference writing a Bash or Perl script that launches one process for each file than everything in C++. But a Bash/Perl/insert_your_favorite_scripting_language_here to recurse all files in a directory is way faster and easier to code than in C++. You can also filter files by regex or whatever other mean (using grep, for example) more easily.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a single root macro, you can try something like the code snippet below. here I add the files to a TChain but you could of course replace the `TChain::Add` with whatever you want.

```
int addfiles(TChain *ch, const char *dirname=".", const char *ext=".root")
{
   int added = 0;
   TSystemDirectory dir(dirname, dirname);
   TList *files = dir.GetListOfFiles();
   if (files) {
      TSystemFile *file;
      TString fname;
      TIter next(files);
      while ((file=(TSystemFile*)next())) {
         fname = file->GetName();
         if (!file->IsDirectory() && fname.EndsWith(ext)) {
         ch->Add(fname); // or call your function on this one file
         ++added;
         }
     }
   }
   return added;
}
```

(Adapted from this root-talk post: http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13666)

Having said that I think the suggestion by @m0skit0 to launch a smaller script each time is a better one than doing what you propose to do above. Root is finicky and having smaller jobs is better.